# Вопрос по грамматике

Tags: грамотная-речь

"..., чтобы участники мероприятия получали коллекционные издания нашей книги, выполняя задания" или "..., чтобы участники мероприятия получали коллекционные издания нашей книги, выполнив задания"?

Comment: Как говорится, оба хуже. По крайней мере без контекста. Хотя бы эту фразу приведите полностью.

Answer (score 1):

Грамматически оба варианта корректны, причем не сильно различаются по смыслу.

*получали коллекционные издания нашей книги, выполняя задания*
Этот вариант в строгом понимании означает получение книги **во время** выполнения задания.

*получали коллекционные издания нашей книги, выполнив задания*
А это подразумевает получение её **после** успешного выполнения.

Если эта разница критична для пишущего, то так и пишите - в зависимости от смысла.
А если нет, то первый вариант смотрится симпатичнее, поскольку деепричастие стоит в той же видовой форме, что и основной глагол (несовершенный вид).